# Boot freeze on asus vivobook s530f nvidia mx150 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, graphics, nvidia-geforce

**Computer Specs**

```
Asus Vivobook s530f
8GB RAM DDR4
Nvidia MX150 (!)
```

**Background**

Successfully installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my computer (specs above). Secure boot off, fast boot off. Partitioned around 230GB for Ubuntu. Used minimum install and option to install 3rd party drivers.

**Problem**

After selecting ubuntu from three options ( ubuntu, advanced options, system setup ) appears blank screen with ubuntu color.

**Boot options:** nomodeset ( quiet splash doesn't make a difference )

Most of the solutions advise nomodeset but I already did that... Any help would be appreciated.

And also this laptop doesn't have a LAN port to connect to a network and install graphics drivers from grub terminal.

Answer (score 0):

CHECK ASUS WEBSITE FOR FIRMWARE UPDATE!!!

Here is a complete video about this problem, actually for an Asus Zenbook: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbxrSaclKRc

Summary of the fix:

add the boot parameter: dis_ucode_ldr to /etc/default/grub 
then: update-grub

More info here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1829620